# How to retrieve the job and customer suffix field using the quickbooks API

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We are building an application that gets data from a QuickBooks online account using the QuickBooks Online API V2. According to the API documentation, we can see that the "Suffix" field is supported for both customer and job tables. However we have noticed this field is not being returned in the API response. Below is a sample response for a job which should have a suffix (the suffix is present in the quickbooks UI). Is this a problem with the API, the API documentation, or our API request?

200
            14
            
                2013-05-08T10:57:55-07:00
                2013-09-17T09:23:39-07:00
            
            Bridget O'Brien276
            
                5165 easy
                Line 2
                Line 3
                Line 4
                Line 5
                Portland
                United States
                OR
                12620
                INVALID
                Billing
            
            
                Primary
                555-5837
            
            
                Fax
                555-5838
            
            
                Mobile
                555-556-9176
            
            
                http://www.customersruscorp.com
            
            
                QBOrocksTest@yahoo.com
            
            Bridget
            Elizabeth
            O'Brien276
            CustomersRus LLC
            
                This is a note.
            
            
                Bill With Parent
                true
            
            
                Preferred Delivery Method
                PRINT
            
            Bridget O'Brien276
            2
            1
            IS_TAXABLE
            2
            
                12
            
            3
            Bridget O'Brien

Answer (score 2):

Just now I've created a customer using IDS V2 API.

Req body -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customer xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
    <TypeOf>Person</TypeOf>
    <Name>John Doe</Name>
    <Suffix>Sr</Suffix>
</Customer>
```

Response (**GetByID**) -

```
<Customer xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:qbp="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:qbo="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo">
    <Id idDomain="QBO">6</Id>
    <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2013-09-19T15:53:47-07:00</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2013-09-19T15:53:47-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <Name>John Doe</Name>
    <WebSite />
    <Email />
    <Suffix>Sr</Suffix>
    <CustomField xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="StringTypeCustomField">
        <DefinitionId>Preferred Delivery Method</DefinitionId>
        <Value>DONT</Value>
    </CustomField>
    <CustomField xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="StringTypeCustomField">
        <DefinitionId>Resale Number</DefinitionId>
    </CustomField>
    <CustomField xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="BooleanTypeCustomField">
        <DefinitionId>Bill With Parent</DefinitionId>
        <Value>false</Value>
    </CustomField>
    <ShowAs>John Doe</ShowAs>
    <OpenBalance>
        <Amount>0</Amount>
    </OpenBalance>
</Customer>
```

It seems, it works in GetByID API call.

**Edit**

But **GetAll** query endpoint doesn't populate suffix attribute. Here is the response.

```
<Customer>
    <Id idDomain="QBO">6</Id>
    <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2013-09-19T15:53:47-07:00</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2013-09-19T15:53:47-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <Name>John Doe</Name>
    <WebSite />
    <Email />
    <CustomField xsi:type="BooleanTypeCustomField">
        <DefinitionId>Bill With Parent</DefinitionId>
        <Value>false</Value>
    </CustomField>
    <CustomField xsi:type="StringTypeCustomField">
        <DefinitionId>Preferred Delivery Method</DefinitionId>
        <Value>DONT</Value>
    </CustomField>
    <ShowAs>John Doe</ShowAs>
    <OpenBalance>
        <Amount>0</Amount>
    </OpenBalance>
</Customer>
```

Thanks